# Почему условный оператор выполняется целых 12мс?

Tags: javascript

Есть небольшой отрезок кода, где я объявил переменную:

```
let proposals_before = Object.keys(proposals).length;
```

Чуть ниже по коду я обращаюсь к этой переменной и проверяю, равно ли её значение 0:

```
if(proposals_before == 0)
```

Отладчик показывает это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я даже и не знаю, как мне правильно вопрос-то задать. Что, почему, как?

Comment: 1. [mcve]? 2. А остальные строки сколько?

Comment: @Qwertiy во всех остальных отрывках кода, где есть вызов `proposals_before` - нормально - 0.1мс. А вот в условии 12мс.

Comment: Предположу, что это из-за отложенного вычисления: `Object.keys(proposals)` не создаётся и не вычисляется до тех пор, пока, собственно, не требуется, что происходит в if-е

Comment: @Lyth где можно почитать об этом "отложенном вычислении"?

Comment: Увы, это лишь догадка, информации по оптимизатору движка у меня нет. Могу предложить слегка поменять код: написать чуть выше `console.log(proposals_before)` или даже `window[proposals_before]=1`, чтобы форсировать предполагаемое вычисление. Если эта строчка станет самой долгой, значит догадка верна.